# How to add month to date in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, export-to-excel

[image]

My requirement is I need to add month column into input column. I need output as exactly same date for every input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below `Date()` formula.

```
=DATE(YEAR(B2),MONTH(B2)+A2,DAY(B2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`=EDATE(start date, number of months)`

[image: excel]